# Should be an infinite scrolling with logos but instead of first image repeating, it starts from beginning

Tags: html, css

I will be replacing the images for security issues but was wondering what was wrong with the code for it to start from the first image instead of having it repeated after the last image?

And also, I have added the "pause" code in the css but it won't pause. Am I missing another piece of code?

Thanks in advance.

```css
.logo-slider {
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
}

.logo-slider img {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.logo-slider img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo-slider::before,
.logo-slider::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(white), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo-slider::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.logo-slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo-slider .logo-slide-track {
  -webkit-animation: logo-scroll 60s linear infinite;
  animation: logo-scroll 60s linear infinite;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.logo-slider .slide {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo-scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}

@keyframes logo-scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Thanks Holdings</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-slider">
    <div class="logo-slide-track">
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://a.com/" target="_blank"><img src="a.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://b.com/" target="_blank"><img src="b.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://c.com/" target="_blank"><img src="c.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://f.com/" target="_blank"><img src="f.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.e.com/" target="_blank"><img src="e.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.f.com/" target="_blank"><img src="f.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.g.com/" target="_blank"><img src="g.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.h.global/" target="_blank"><img src="h.png" alt="y" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.i.com/" target="_blank"><img src="i.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.j.com/" target="_blank"><img src="j.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.k.com" target="_blank"><a href="k.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.l.com" target="_blank"><a href="l.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _Am I missing another piece of code?_ How about the complete code? ;-)

Comment: Sorry.. New here and still trying to figure out how to post the code here..

Updated: posted screenshots instead

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post code. There's a great snippet editor on this very site

Comment: I got it figured now.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you're attempting to move the entire `.slide-track` element instead of each `.slide` element separately. This means that the `.slide` elements cannot begin repeating until they are all off of the screen, since the animation is applied to the `.slide-track`. Once they are all off the screen, the animation will begin again where it started, in the center of the screen.

Another issue is that the `.slide` elements do not begin off of the right side of the screen, so they do not return to that position once the animation is completed. To solve this issue, you can begin the elements off the right side of the screen and use a negative `animation-delay` property to move them along.

```css
.logo-slider {
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
}

.logo-slider img {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.logo-slider img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo-slider::before,
.logo-slider::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(white), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo-slider::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.logo-slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo-slider .logo-slide-track {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
  background-color: yellow; /* TESTING */
}

.logo-slider .slide {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  
  -webkit-animation: logo-scroll 60s linear infinite;
  animation: logo-scroll 60s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -8s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -7.5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -7s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -6.5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -6s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -5.5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -4.5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(10) {
  animation-delay: -3.5s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(11) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
}
.logo-slider .slide:nth-child(12) {
  animation-delay: -2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo-scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100vw);
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}

@keyframes logo-scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100vw);
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Thanks Holdings</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-slider">
    <div class="logo-slide-track">
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://a.com/" target="_blank"><img src="a.png" alt="A" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://b.com/" target="_blank"><img src="b.png" alt="B" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://c.com/" target="_blank"><img src="c.png" alt="C" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://d.com/" target="_blank"><img src="d.png" alt="D" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.e.com/" target="_blank"><img src="e.png" alt="E" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.f.com/" target="_blank"><img src="f.png" alt="F" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.g.com/" target="_blank"><img src="g.png" alt="G" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.h.global/" target="_blank"><img src="h.png" alt="H" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.i.com/" target="_blank"><img src="i.png" alt="I" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.j.com/" target="_blank"><img src="j.png" alt="J" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.k.com" target="_blank"><img src="k.png" alt="K" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.l.com" target="_blank"><img src="l.png" alt="L" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This isn't a perfect example, but it should help to show where the problem lies.

Let me know if you have any questions on how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
One more question though. for some reason the last three images seem to just disappear instead of scrolling through all the way to the left end. How can I fix this? >.< I have changed the duration time but it did not seem to work.

Comment: No problem! To fix the issue, you're going to have to increase the distance that the images move off screen at the end of the animation. This may also require you to tinker with the animation delay on the elements to fix any changes that may have occurred. 

There may be a formula you can come up for this, but I have no idea off the top of my head what it might be.

Comment: Actually, the distance it moves off screen would be at least -1 * (150 + 5 + 5) * 12 in this case. (move left * (width of a slide + padding left + padding right) * the number of slides). The animation delay and duration of the animation will have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: thank you it seems to work now!
though, my last question if you can help me out one more time.. How could I get the first logo to occur right after the last logo? Is it possible to edit it with my current code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Having it infinitely loop without having a big gap between end and start of the logo. Like have the first logo right after the last logo when it's done with the first loop. Currently, with this code, it has a big gap after the last logo and then it starts the first logo again.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem as mentioned before is you're trying to move the whole block of images, and the  obvious answer is to move each img on it's own, also another problem is that your animation isn't coded properly to achieve your desired behavior, with little tinkering i managed to get to work as you described, hope it works :)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo-slider {
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
}

.logo-slider img {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.logo-slider img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo-slider::before,
.logo-slider::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(white), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo-slider::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.logo-slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo-slider .slide {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: logo-scroll 15s linear infinite;
}

.logo-slider .logo-slide-track {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes logo-scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(calc(250px * 7));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-slider">
  <div class="logo-slide-track">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="a.png" alt="A" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="b.png" alt="B" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="c.png" alt="C" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="d.png" alt="D" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="e.png" alt="E" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="f.png" alt="F" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="g.png" alt="G" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="h.png" alt="H" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="i.png" alt="I" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="j.png" alt="J" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="k.png" alt="K" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="l.png" alt="L" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it is still not the desired effect, if you want the first img to appear after the last image and so on, this can't be achieved with only css, you'll have to include js maybe some plugin to do it for you.